# CSS Image fit width and height

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make an image fit to its container. The problem is, that I can only set it to fit to the width `width: 100%` or the height `height: 100%` but not both.

Basically it should check weather container length or height is smaller compared to image width and height (normalized) and adapt it to that. And it should also center the image.

This is standard behavior in Windows Photo Viewer. The image is always visible, centered and preservers the ratio. I am trying to make it exactly like that.

PS: I would prefer a css solution. But if it is impossible/very painful, js is also ok.

PSPS: Sorry if this is a duplicate. I searched the internet and found similar questions, but none of them seemed to had the right answer.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Is the container a fixed size? Is it the same proportion as the image?

Comment: @Huangism Thats the point. The container size depends on the window size of the browser. So it can be anything and it can change to anything.

Comment: Would be great to see a codepen/jsfiddle of what you have so far.

Comment: @RichardHealy My solution is not very good. It does not consider to adjust if the height is too small, so the image gets cropped. 
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/mug2eg2ofvjyfz7/AACDcTGfp_IArj4Nk7sfNxP8a?dl=0)

Comment: Put it as a background-image. Apply `background-size: contain;`.

Comment: Yup contain was the solution. I added the background-position: center; and now it is perfect! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set image with CSS `background-image`, like this:

```
div{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/cjgKmvp.jpg");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/ue49awaL/8/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is, that is won't preserve the aspect ratio of the image.

Comment: Then use `background-size: cover;` instead :) See the following demo: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/ue49awaL/5/

Comment: Haha I think at this point I can say, that I have tried out just about every conventional css method ;) The problem with size: cover; is that it crops the image.

Comment: What you want then? Because it's not possible adjust an image with different size to it parent div without "scale" it or "crop" it.

Comment: I didn't say that it is not allowed to scale the image. It should just have the same width/height ratio when scaling it.

Comment: `background-size: contain;` also does not produce what you need?

Comment: Oh wow! This actually works! Thank you :D
Would you like to make another answer so I can mark it?

Comment: @Haeri I update this answer, you can accept it now :)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few solutions to this. None of them perfect. And it usually depends if you want the image to be cropped or not.

If you're fine with cropping you can try something like:

```
<div class="image"></div>
<style>
    .image {
          width:250px;
          height:150px;
          background-image:url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/');
          background-size:cover;
    }
</style>
```

If you don't want it to crop then it will depend how you want to lay out the image (or images). Here are a couple of examples:

- http://healy.rocks/gallery1 - Responsive gallery layout
- http://healy.rocks/gallery2 - Pinterest css layout with mansonry.js
- http://healy.rocks/gallery3 - Simple row css layout
- http://healy.rocks/gallery3b - Google images css layout wth
  rowGrid.js

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The image is the company logo, so it should better not be cropped xD. And thanks for the links to the gallery, but since this is only one image, I don't think I'd need an entire js library for displaying galleries...

Comment: So the image needs to be the exact same size as the container always? Is it the image driving the width/height of the container OR the container driving the width/height of the image?

Comment: The container size is given. The image should adapt to it. And the image doesn't need to be the exact size of the container. It should just adjust its scale, so that the image ratio is preserved, none of the image is cropped and that it is centered where it is not filling the container (eg if it is adapting to the width, it should center vertically)

Comment: @Haeri should the image go beyond its original width / height also?

Comment: How about something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/sc53yya3/6/ Can't really tell the effect you want.